# Number theory Mod divisibility problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a number theory problem in my textbook, and I cant seem to solve it, the problem goes:
$$1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - .... - 1/(p-1) = \frac{a}{(p-1)!}$$ and we have to show that $$a =\frac{2- 2^p}{p} \pmod p.$$
Can anyone please help me solve this please? Because I have like tried to rearrange the sums by applying the Wolstenholmes congruence, but I just cant get it to be in a divisible form of modp. How can I start proceeding with this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is [a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/218894/11619). The question is much rarer than many others, so I won't cast the first vote to close in case somebody can give a different answer or add something interesting.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thank you, I will look at this post and see if I understand it.